# Relatively Prime Gaussian Integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> For $a,b ∈Z$ show that $a + bi$ and $a − bi$ are relatively prime  iff $(a, b)=1$

For "$⟸$" I tried to get a contradiction using norm argument, but I did not reach to my goal!

If any one can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any common divisor of $x$ and $y$ is a common divisor of $x+y$ and $x-y$.

Comment: That does not get us all the way to relative primality.  It can't, because ... see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your background, but I guess you would not be able to solve your problem without a minimal knowledge of the properties wrt division of the gaussian ring $\mathbf Z [i]$. Let us first start from scratch and see what we can do. Suppose that a *non unit* $z \in \mathbf Z [i]$ divides both $a \pm bi$. Then by elementary manipulations, $z$ divides $2a$ and $2b$, but this division takes place in $\mathbf Z [i]$, so you cannot yet exploit the hypothesis that $a, b$ are coprime in $\mathbf Z$.

The extra property which you need is that $\mathbf Z [i]$ is a PID, i.e. any ideal in it  is principal, so that the decomposition of any element of $\mathbf Z [i]$ into a product of irreducible (= prime) elements exists and is unique up to units (= invertible elements). The units here are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$. The uniqueness of the prime decomposition allows to reduce your problem to the case where the common divisor $z$ above is irreducible, call it $\pi$, which will divide both $2a, 2b$. Taking norms shows that $N(\pi)=\pi.\bar {\pi}$ divides both $4a^2, 4b^2$ in $\mathbf Z$. Because $a, b$ are coprime, $N(\pi)$ will divide $4$, i.e. $N(\pi)=2,4$. But the prime decomposition of $2$ is $(1+i)(1-i)$, so that $\pi.\bar {\pi}=(1+i)(1-i)$ or $(1+i)^2(1-i)^2$. It follows from the uniqueness of the prime decomposition that $\pi=1\pm i$ up to units.

Of course more elaborate considerations on the arithmetic of the Gaussian integers could help to shorten the arguments.

Comment: If $z$ divides $2a$ and $2b$ in $\mathbf Z [i]$ and $a, b$ are coprime in $\mathbf Z$ then $z$ divides $2$ in $\mathbf Z [i]$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim as written appears to be false.  If $a=b=1$ then these are of course relatively prime,  but each of $1+i$ and $1-i$ is a Gaussian integer times the other.  Properly, either common factors of $1\pm i$ must be allowed or else $a$ and $b$ should be specified as not both odd.

Comment: what if the common factors are allowed? can we prove it by induction on the norm?

Comment: Look at Arturo Martin's comment to the question.  You should be able to prove that $1\pm i$ and their negatives are the only common factors there could be apart from the trivial ones.  So we do not have to allow common factors more generally.  The norm gas little to do with Arturo's hint, really.